# Construction of elliptic equation with Neumann boundary condition from a minimization problem

Tags: elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

My question mainly concern about how to construct a elliptic equation with Neumann boundary condition from a minimization problem.

Let $B=B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $E : H^1(B) \to \mathbb{R}$
$$E(u)= \int_{B}|\nabla u|^2+(u^2-1)^2 dx - \int_{\partial B}Q(u)d\mathcal{H}^2$$
We assume that $u_0 \in W^{1,2}$ to be the minimizer of the functional $E$ in the configuration space
$$K=\{u\in W^{1,2}(B:\mathbb{R})\}.$$
Since $u_0$ is the critical point of the functional, we let $\xi \in K$, we obtain the equation 
$$\int_B \nabla u \cdot \nabla \xi + 4(u^2-1)u \xi dx - \int_{\partial B }Q'(u)\xi d\mathcal{H}^2 = 0. $$
If we further require that $\xi$ vanishes on the boundary, we have the EL equation
$$\int_B \nabla u \cdot \nabla \xi + 4(u^2-1)u \,\xi dx = 0. $$
Suppose we also have that $u \in H^2(B)$, we have
$$\int_B -\Delta u \, \xi + 4(u^2-1)u \xi dx + \int_{\partial B } \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}\xi- Q'(u)\xi d\mathcal{H}^2 = 0. $$
We finally obtain the equation
$$\Delta u = 4(u^2-1)u \,\text{  in } B \,\text{ and }\, \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=Q'(u) \,\text{ on }\, \partial B.$$

My main goal is to prove the minimizer $u_0$ solve the above equation weakly with the desried Neumann boundary condition. However, my question is how to obtain the $H^2$ bound of $u$? I think we can apply standard estimate to obtain $H^2_{loc}$. If we do not have the fact that $u \in H^2(B)$, we may hard to have the existence of $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ on the boundary by trace theorem.

Comment: From the context, it looks like your "$E:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$" (third line) should be "$E:H^1(B)\to \mathbb{R}$".

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: is the goal here to show that the minimising $u_0\in H^1(B)$ is a $H^2(B)$ function satisfying your Neumann problem?

Comment: @DCM Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u\in H^1(B)$ be a minimising value of $E:H^1(B)\to \mathbb{R}_+$. Then $E'(u)=0$ in the sense that

$$
E'(u)v = 
\int_B [\nabla u \cdot \nabla v + 4(u^2-1)uv ] dx - \int_{\partial B} Q'(u)v \hspace{.5pc}d\mathcal{H}^2 = 0
$$

for all $v\in H^1(B)$. This implies, in particular, that

$$
\int_B [-u \Delta v + 4(u^2-1)uv] \hspace{.5pc}dx = 0
$$

for $v\in \mathscr{D}(B)$ (this uses the fact that $v$ and all its derivatives vanish on $\partial B$ if it has compact support in $B$). Having this last equation hold for all $v\in \mathscr{D}(B)$ is exactly the statement that

$$
\Delta u = 4(u^2-1)u \hspace{1pc}\mbox{in $B$  }
$$

in the sense of distributions. The interior equation in the distributional sense is therefore just what you get from regarding $E'(u)$ itself as a distribution (i.e. by restricting it to $\mathscr{D}(B))$.

For each compact subset $K$ of $B$, take $\psi_K\in \mathscr{D}(B)$ with $\psi_{|K}=1$. Then considering the action of $E'(u)$ on $\{v(1-\psi_K):v\in C^\infty(\bar B),\mbox{$K\subset B$ compact}\}$ should - I think - also give you a weak form of your boundary condition.

I might be wrong, but I think that it's only once you have your interior equation in a (weak or distributional) form which does *a priori* involve the assumption that $u\in H^2(B)$ that it's time time to start worrying about regularity. In particular, you may be able to establish that $u\in H^2(B)$ *using* the fact that it is a $H^1$ solution to your PDE.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For a general $H^1(B)$ function, I think it may be have a well-defined derivative on the boundary and also the $\Delta u$ (ever in weak or distributional sense?). However my main goal is as the title, I do not know if I construct it in the correct way. I also look for another construction if mine is not good enough.

Comment: I think the general pattern you follow is sound. Assuming $E:H^1(B)\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, a necessary condition for $u\in H^1(B)$ to be a minimiser is that $E'(u)v = 0$ for *all* $v\in H^1(B)$. Choosing $v\in H^1_0(B)$ gives you your "EL" equation, for example. The key thing is that $u$ has to satisfy the $E'(u)v = 0$ whatever $v\in H^1(B)$ you choose, which is the main mechanism through which you're able to deduce things about its behaviour.

Comment: In particular, I'd be inclined to see what you get by using Green's identity (thought of in a distributional sense, at least initially) in the equation in your third display, and seeing what drops out of that for different choices of $v$.

Comment: I think the slickest way to get the interior equation and the boundary equation alone is by choosing test functions $v$ which satisfy a suitable PDE of their own (a PDE designed to make one of the two integrals vanish).

Comment: I nice analogy here is 'plotting the graph of a function'. $E'(u)$ is a linear function(al) on $H^1(B)$; we learn about its `shape' behaviour by plugging in values and seeing what we get. The behaviour of $E'(u)$ then tells us things about $u$.

Comment: Sorry ,finally I see what you concern. Suppose we have that $u \in H^2$, then we can integrate by part to obtain$$\int_B -\Delta u \, \xi + 4(u^2-1)u \xi dx + \int_{\partial B } \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}\xi- Q'(u)\xi d\mathcal{H}^2 = 0. $$
The PDE makes the first part vanish, so we have 
$$\int_{\partial B } \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}\xi- Q'(u)\xi d\mathcal{H}^2 = 0. $$ for any $\xi \in H^1(B_1)$ . So I think I also get the boundary condition in the pointwise sense.

Comment: @mnmn1993: just out of curiosity... where does your $E$ come from? In particular, did you start with the functional or the PDE?

Comment: I start from a functional. The functional is called Ginzburg Landau functional.